# How can I stop web-scraping dataes, when i find the value?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, append, findall

I have got this code, which one i can search the all table called "ctable" on a website with Python 2.7. But i want to stop it, when it is reaching on of this "ctable" with the value XXXX. I need until this value XXXX. So if it is finding this text i want to stop webscraping these tables.

Is it possible?

Here my code:

```js
soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')

datatable=[]
for ctable in soup.find_all('table',  "ctable" )[:-1]:
    for record in ctable.find_all('tr'):
        temp_data = []
        for data in record.find_all('td'):
            temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
        datatable.append(temp_data)
```

I tried this:

```js
datatable=[]
for ctable in soup.find_all('table',  "ctable" )[:-1]:
    for record in ctable.find_all('tr'):
        temp_data = []
        for data in record.find_all('td'):
            temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
            if 'modul' in data.text:
                break         
datatable.append(temp_data)
```

Comment: please give real link from where you're scraping data, for I could check it on my PC

Comment: Can we go to private?

Comment: yep, let's go, but I don't know how to switch to chat=)

Comment: ahh, and i havent got any right to open a private chat yet :S
i cant send you this link, because this is from a log in website, with a captcha security..so i decided that i download into a txt this html source, and after i read it in python, where i can looking for these tables.

Comment: this break operator what you suggested for me, this isn't work, because i lose all datatable before this break command!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a `break` operator in your code:

```
    ...
    (your code above)
datatable=[]
stop = 0
for ctable in soup.find_all('table',  "ctable" )[:-1]:
    if stop == 1:
        break
    for record in ctable.find_all('tr'):
        if stop == 1:
            break
        temp_data = []
        for data in record.find_all('td'):
            temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
            if 'modul' in data.text:
                stop = 1
                break         
        datatable.append(temp_data)
```

I didn't pay enough attention that you have a triple `for` loop. Maybe now it will work?

I added `break` to every loop.

Alternative `if` and `break`:

```
datatable=[]
stop = 0
for ctable in soup.find_all('table',  "ctable" )[:-1]:
    for record in ctable.find_all('tr'):
        temp_data = []
        for data in record.find_all('td'):
            temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
            if 'modul' in data.text:
                stop = 1
                break         
        datatable.append(temp_data)
        if stop == 1:
            break
    if stop == 1:
        break
```

Comment: This is not important in my code : [:-1]

It isnt work, there are some syntax error in your code

Comment: can you copy it here?

Comment: yep, that's my bad=) should be double "=" in `if` statements. Fixed

Comment: well,I defined it at the top - `stop = 0`. Have _you_ defined it?=)

Comment: It is work, but this isnt what  i am looking for :( 
I need the dataes BEFORE this break command. And with this code i lose these dataes. o.O

Comment: then just replace `if` statements from start to the end of each loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148287/discussion-between-dmitriy-fialkovskiy-and-tardos93).